# How to assign values to the nested objects dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a project and I need to be able to do the following:

Say, We have `Aa` class that is configuration class:

```
public class Aa
{
    public Bb BbName { set; get; }
    public string Dd { set; get; }
}


public class Bb
{
    public string bb { set; get; }
    public string cc { set; get; }
}
```

I want to fetch variables from environment in order to assign them to the respective properties. Here is what I mean: as a simulation of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`, let's use `Dictionary<string, string>`.
Setup will look like this:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("Dd", "236.154");
dic.Add("BbName.bb", "value_for_Bb.bb"); // as you can see, I'm using nested object's full
dic.Add("BbName.cc", "value_for_Bb.cc"); // path, in order to be able to identify it
```

Then I wrote a method, which looks like this:

```
private static void ReadPropertiesRecursive<T>(T obj, Type type, List<string> prefixes)
{

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            prefixes.Add(property.Name);
            ReadPropertiesRecursive(obj, property.PropertyType, prefixes);
            prefixes.Remove(property.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            var propertyFullName = prefixes != null && prefixes.Count > 0 ? $"{prefixes.Aggregate((i, j) => i + "." + j)}.{property.Name}" : property.Name;

            property.SetValue(obj, dic[propertyFullName]);

            Console.WriteLine(propertyFullName); // just for debugging
        }
    }
}
```

So, using recursion, I'm able to reach all nested objects of the given `Type` and the only thing that is left is assigning corresponding values to them. I'm trying to do that on `property.SetValue(obj, dic[propertyFullName]);`, but it throws an error, and it makes sense: obj is a "root" object, not the one that I want to assign values to, directly. So, I probably need to pass here not `obj`, but rather an instance of `property`, which is `obj`'s property. Is that correct? Will that work? If yes, how should I do that?

Comment: Split property name with "." and make your function recursive.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, and I'm doing that correctly - I know, because I can see it when printing out `propertyFullName`.

Comment: Ah, you're saying **split** property name... I'm sorry, I don't understand what exactly are you saying or how it can help me.

Comment: Few hours before I'm at my computer, I'll post something if someone else didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That did the trick:

```
private static void ReadPropertiesRecursive<Tt>(Tt obj, Type type, List<string> prefixes)
{

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            prefixes.Add(property.Name);
            var val = property.GetValue(obj);
            if (val == null)
                val = Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
            property.SetValue(obj, val);
            ReadPropertiesRecursive(val, property.PropertyType, prefixes);
            prefixes.Remove(property.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            var propertyFullName = prefixes != null && prefixes.Count > 0 ? $"{prefixes.Aggregate((i, j) => i + "." + j)}.{property.Name}" : property.Name;

            property.SetValue(obj, dic[propertyFullName]);

            Console.WriteLine(propertyFullName);
        }
    }
}
```